# divide STL vector by a scalar operator overload

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I'm trying to overload the division operator to be able to divide an std::vector by a double scalar with the following:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> operator/(const double& a, const std::vector<T>& b) {
    std::vector<T> c(b.size());
    for(int i=0;i<b.size();++i)
        c[i] = b[i] / a;
    return c;
}
```

If I then try to compute:

```
std::vector<double> M(Z.size());
M = Z / a;
```

where Z is a valid std::vector.

The compiler (Xcode) stops me saying "Invalid operands to invalid expression ('std::vector' and 'double'). Can anyone tell me why my template does not work and recommend me a suitable alternative, please?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Have you tried `std::valarray`?

Comment: `const double& a, const std::vector<T>& b` you should swap them.

Comment: Did you mean `a / Z` ?

Comment: Guys, it just unbelievable how I couldn't realise it! Thanks

Comment: Too lazy to dig up chapter and verse, but I'm pretty sure this is illegal regardless of order. At least one of the arguments of an overloaded function must be a User-Defined Type not from `std::`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator overload declarations in C++ are sensitive to argument order. Putting the vector first in the argument list would be more conventional.

Try either

`std::vector<T> operator/(const std::vector<T>& b, const double& a)`

or

`M = a / Z;`

Having said that, I agree with the comment from @krzaq that you really may benefit from looking at `std::valarray` and not reinventing the wheel. If you're goal is try learn more about templates and operator overloads, or if you have another goal in mind, knock yourself out.

Comment: Note: overloading operators for built-in or std types will suffer from 2-phase lookup issues